# What's a good, robust, ASYNC way to check if URLs exist from a Play controller?

Tags: java, asynchronous, playframework

I originally tried this:

```
private static boolean checkUrlsAreReachable(String... urls) {
    checkArgument(urls.length > 0);

    List<F.Promise<WS.HttpResponse>> promises = newArrayList();
    for (String url : urls) {
        promises.add(WS.url(url).followRedirects(true).timeout("30s").getAsync());
    }

    List<WS.HttpResponse> results = await(F.Promise.waitAll(promises));
    for (WS.HttpResponse response : results) {
        if (!response.success()) {
            logger.debug("Failed accessing one of " + Joiner.on(", ").join(urls));
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

But I found several caveats:

- I'm getting an exception on WS.url(url) if the URL in question does not resolve well (e.g. `http://a.com/`).
- At least when debugging, it seems the call to `getAsync()` blocks ... is it really async in production? I know Play has fewer thread in Dev mode, but I thought the call wouldn't even start executing at this point.
- If one of the URLs is not reachable, I'm not sure how to log which failed (how to access the URL from the WS.HttpResponse object)

So, I turned to use sync HTTP instead of async. The following implementation seems to work:

```
private static boolean checkUrlsAreReachable(String... urls) {
    checkArgument(urls.length > 0);

    List<F.Promise<Boolean>> promises = newArrayList();
    for (final String url : urls) {
        promises.add(new Job<Boolean>(){
            @Override
            public Boolean doJobWithResult() throws Exception {
                try {
                    WS.HttpResponse result = WS.url(url).followRedirects(true)
                        .timeout("30s").get();
                    return result.success();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }.now());
    }
    F.Promise<List<Boolean>> allResults = F.Promise.waitAll(promises);
    List<Boolean> booleans = await(allResults);
    return Booleans3.and(booleans);
}
```

Is there a way to make the async implementation work?

Answer (score 0):

set job pool setting part in application.conf

```
# Jobs executor
# ~~~~~~
# Size of the Jobs pool
play.jobs.pool=20

# Execution pool
# ~~~~~
# Default to 1 thread in DEV mode or (nb processors + 1) threads in PROD mode.
# Try to keep a low as possible. 1 thread will serialize all requests (very useful for debugging purpose)
play.pool=5
```

And just put the checking part in a job, such as CheckingJob, and start it using

```
new CheckingJob().now()
```

it will be async.